# import CSV file, remove a line, export CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import, modify and then export a CSV file for doing bulk delivery's.

essentially, i would like to open the file, remove a specific column from it, check for any duplicates and remove if there are any and then export to another CSV file.

my code is as follows

```
import csv

with open ('book1.csv', 'r') as in_file,  open ('ammended.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    read_file = csv.DictReader(in_file)

    for row in read_file:
        print(row)
        row.pop('flavour')
        print(row)
```

output -

```
{'name': 'me', 'address': '34', 'postcode': 'hhhh', 'flavour':'lemon'}
{'name': 'me', 'address': '34', 'postcode': 'hhhh'}
{'name':'me', 'address': '34', 'postcode': 'hhhh', 'flavour': 'lime'}
{'name':'me', 'address': '34', 'postcode': 'hhhh'}
{'name': 'you', 'address':'35', 'postcode': 'hlhl', 'flavour': 'strawberry'} 
{'name': 'you','address': '35', 'postcode': 'hlhl'}
```

so far im happy that it imports and removes the correct line, but then how can i check for duplicate lines and then export to a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you trying `pandas` for your task.

To install `pandas` type in your terminal:

```
pip install pandas
```

In your code try doing:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('book1.csv')   # Reading data
df = df.drop('flavour', axis=1) # Dropping column
df = df.drop_duplicates()       # Removing duplicates
df.to_csv('ammended.csv')       # Saving filtered data
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked. However it has generated a new column with what i assume are the index number of a list. anyway to remove these?

Comment: @BILLYBOB Sure, just add `index=False` into `.to_csv()` method. For example in your case: ```df.to_csv('ammended.csv', index=False)```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the rows to a list and use the set function to remove duplicates:

```py
import csv
import json

with open ('book.csv', 'r') as in_file:
    read_file = csv.DictReader(in_file)
    row_list = []
    for row in read_file:
        row.pop('flavour')
        print(row) 
        row_list.append(str(row)) # convert the dict to a string to make it hashable
   
    no_dups = set(row_list) # remove duplicates
    
# now write to a new file
with open('output.csv', "w") as out_file:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'address', 'postcode']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in no_dups:
        row = row.replace("'", '"') # json needs double quotes
        writer.writerow(json.loads(row)) # convert string to dict (sorts of) and write the line
```

EDIT: I changed the answer to actually work. Sorry for the previous error it produced.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. however i did try this but it threw a TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Oh, I did not actually test this. I'll prepare a csv file real quick and test

Comment: I changed the answer. It should work now.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :)